# django how to sum item * quantity for each items in cart

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

How to sum each items in cart * quantity, example first item 10 *- quantity = total, The second one item x * quantity = total, this suma give me the total all items in cart not for each items.

```
def add_produktshitje(request, shitje_id):
shitje = get_object_or_404(Shitje, id=shitje_id)
suma= Produ.objects.filter(shitje_id=shitje.pk).aggregate(totals=Sum(F('sasia')*F('cmimi'), output_field=FloatField()))
return render(request, 'polls/add_produktshitje.html', {'shitje':shitje,'suma':suma})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s because you are using "aggregate" wich is meant to get totals. You should use "annotate" to get the kind of partial aggregation you want.

Change this line

```
suma= Produ.objects.filter(shitje_id=shitje.pk).aggregate(totals=Sum(F('sasia')*F('cmimi'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

for this line

```
suma= Produ.objects.filter(shitje_id=shitje.pk).values("product_name").annotate(totals=Sum(F('sasia')*F('cmimi'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

Note that I added `values("product_name")`, this way you choose the field on which you are going to group yor annotation. I just put "product_name" couse you mentioned a cart, but replace that string fro whatever field your need.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

Hope this helps.

Comment: thnx its work, {{suma}} in template show all queryset list <QuerySet [{'produkt_id': 1, 'totals': 600.0}, {'produkt_id': 2, 'totals': 60000.0}]> , i try  {{suma.totals}}  but dont show nothing.how can i do show just the totals 60000.0

Comment: You should iterate over the queryset to print the values in template. In this case you can add an if clause to show the one you want.  {% for x in suma %}
    {% if x.produkt_id == 2 %}
        {{ x.totals }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}